# Regex to identify phone number

Tags: php, regex, drupal-7

I have a requirement where I have to hide phone number in messages provided by users. I already have one regular expression which is as follows:

```
/\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})/
```

But this can only identify mobile numbers of following formats:

```
9876543210
```

I want it to cover following formats too:

> 987 654 3210
>
> 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
>
> (987) 654 3210
>
> (987) (654) (3210)

In all the above formats, spaces can be replaced by either '-' or '.'. Also, '(' and ')' can be replaced by '[' and ']'.

Also, is it possible to identify phone numbers which are mentioned with strings instead of digits, like

> Nine eight seven six five four three two one zero
>
> Any combination of digits and strings

**EDIT:** Adding my function which is hiding contact numbers if any from content:

```
function hide_contact_number($description) {
// Find contact number and hide it!
$regex = "/\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})/";
/*$regex = "/[\([]?([0-9]{3})[\)\]]?[-. ]?[\([]?([0-9]{3})[\)\]]?[-. ]?[\([]?([0-9]{4})[\)\]]?|([0-9])[-. ]([0-9])[-. ]([0-9])[-. ]([0-9])[-. ]([0-9])[-. ]([0-9])[-. ]([0-9])[-. ]([0-9])[-. ]([0-9])[-. ]([0-9])/";*/
if(preg_match_all($regex, $description, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE)) {
    foreach($matches as $matchkey => $match) {
        foreach($match as $key => $value) {
            $index = 0;
            $length = 0;
            if(is_array($value)) {
                if(is_numeric($value[0]) && strlen($value[0]) >= 10) {
                    $index = $value[1];
                    $length = strlen($value[0]);
                } else if(strlen($value[1]) >= 10) {
                    $index = $value[0];
                    $length = strlen($value[1]);
                } else {
                    // TODO: Do nothing
                }
            }

            if($length > 0) {
                // length - 2 => 2 places before end of email id including 1 of index + 1
                $description = substr_replace($description, str_repeat("*", $length-2), $index+1, $length-2);
            }
        }
    }
}

return $description;
```

}

The above function does not identify and hide all the number sequences I have mentioned. Even @CCH's solution does not help. Is anything wrong with this function?

Comment: You should first try to understand a bit more what the regexp you have is doing. It matches more than just `9876543210`, but also : `987 654 3210`  or 
`987-654-3210` or    
`987.654.3210`.  
 Have a look at the website https://regex101.com/ that will help you understand better how it works.

Comment: Yes I understand that, but in reality, when I try to run '987 654 3210' or '987-654-3210' or '987.654.3210', it does not work.

Comment: Then you'll have to provide some more code on what is not working, because as you can see here : https://regex101.com/r/h9631Z/2 your regexp matches the 3 cases above.

Comment: Have added my function which identifies numbers and hide them. Please check.

Comment: You made my eyes bleed :) See my updated answer, `preg_replace` is enough to replace matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This :

> `[\([]?([0-9]{3})[\)\]]?[-. ]?[\([]?([0-9]{3})[\)\]]?[-. ]?[\([]?([0-9]{4})[\)\]]?|([0-9])[-. ]([0-9])[-. ]([0-9])[-. ]([0-9])[-. ]([0-9])[-. ]([0-9])[-. ]([0-9])[-. ]([0-9])[-. ]([0-9])[-. ]([0-9])`

will match all your examples.
Demo here :
https://regex101.com/r/h9631Z/4

For a full php function, use this :

```
function hide_contact_number($description) {
$re = '/[\([]?([0-9]{3})[\)\]]?[-. ]?[\([]?([0-9]{3})[\)\]]?[-. ]?[\([]?([0-9]{4})[\)\]]?|([0-9])[-. ]([0-9])[-. ]([0-9])[-. ]([0-9])[-. ]([0-9])[-. ]([0-9])[-. ]([0-9])[-. ]([0-9])[-. ]([0-9])[-. ]([0-9])/';
$subst = '*** *** ***';
return preg_replace($re, $subst, $description);
}
```

You can change $subst to set what it will replace the matches to.

Full demo here : https://repl.it/FnSp/3

Comment: I tried your solution, though it works on demo, when I include it in my function it does not identify all the cases mentioned. Please check my function in edit

Answer (score 1):

Posting this for anyone who is looking for similar solution. With the help of CCH's answer above (accepted) and dquijada's, I came up with following function to hide contact number from the content.

```
function hide_contact_number($description) {
    $search = array('zero', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine');
    $replace = array('0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9');
    $description = str_ireplace($search, $replace, $description);

    $regex = '/[\([]?([0-9]{3})[\)\]]?[-. ]?[\([]?([0-9]{3})[\)\]]?[-. ]?[\([]?([0-9]{4})[\)\]]?' .
    '|([0-9])[-. ]*([0-9])[-. ]*([0-9])[-. ]*([0-9])[-. ]*([0-9])[-. ]*([0-9])[-. ]*([0-9])[-. ]*([0-9])[-. ]*([0-9])[-. ]*([0-9])[-. ]*/';
    $description = preg_replace($regex, str_repeat('*', 10), $description);

    return $description;
}
```

**FYI:** This has only one issue, i.e., if there is a number mentioned in text format, it will get converted to the actual digit. For. e.g. if there is the following line:

```
This one is the very good case to solve.
```

The above line will get converted as follows:

```
This 1 is the very good case to solve.
```

Answer (score 0):

One fast and easy solution to all this cases is to create a temporal variable with only numbers.

I don't know any PHP, but in JS (you certainly can adapt it) it would be:

```
aux = string.replace(/\D/g, '')
```

And then apply your regex to the aux variable.

A regex to match all your cases would be pretty ugly, but here I go:

```
\(?\d\s*\d\s*\d\)\s*\(?\d\s*\d\s*\d\)\s*\(?\d\s*\d\s*\d\s*\d)
```

And the word stuff, you can always do a:

```
number = string
    .replace(/one/g, '1')
    .replace(/two/g, '2')
    .replace(/three/g, '3')
    .replace(/four/g, '4')
    .replace(/five/g, '5')
    .replace(/six/g, '6')
    .replace(/seven/g, '7')
    .replace(/eight/g, '8')
    .replace(/nine/g, '9')
    .replace(/zero/g, '0');
```

(You can keep adding numbers to support, like ten, eleven, etc..)
Also you can use a regexp to match the combinations of digits and strings. For example, modifying the one I used:

```
\(?d|one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine\s*d|one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine\s*d|one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine\)?\s*\(?d|one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine\s*d|one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine\s*d|one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine\)?\s*\(?d|one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine\s*d|one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine\s*d|one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine\s*d|one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine\)?
```

(I would really not recommend doing this)